# Soap client cannot connect to web service after bea weblogic deployment

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-rpc, weblogic9.x

I wrote below method to call soap client which connects to web service. below code work fine in test class but after deploy my war into bea weblogic9 i got HTTP/1.1 500 error. and i am can not what is wrong in my code as it works fine locally.`

```
public boolean isServiceReady(String msisdn) throws Exception
{
  logger.info("check if the service ready or not for " + msisdn);
  if("".equals(msisdn))
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("no active msisdn for logged user");
    }
  ServiceReadyClient nfcClient = ServiceReadyClient.getInstance(true);
  ServiceReadyServices services = nfcClient.getServices();

  if(services == null)
    {
      throw new ServiceReadyClientException("NFC Client not ready yet");
    }
  IsServiceReadyResponse result = services.isServiceReady("tel:" + msisdn, CSS_CLIENT);
  return (result != null && result.getReadinessStatus() != null) ? 
           "YES".equals(result.getReadinessStatus().getValue()) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ServiceReadyServices  and ServiceReadyClient are from your custom API's? 
Try passing Web service URL to above API classes.

Comment: yes, it is custome APIs. The API classes works fine in test client and in other desktop application and it provided by VF.